# Uploaded GIF on Facebook is displayed as a static image

Tags: c#, facebook, image, gif, restsharp

I've implemented a method to share a post on Facebook. The issue I am facing is that uploaded GIF image is displayed as a static image instead of animated GIF.

When uploading an image through Facebook, results are similar. I've tried implementing an alternative solution by posting to '/me/feed' and specifying 'picture' and 'link' parameters, once again it resulted in static image.

Is there an alternative any approach available for this issue?

```
/// <summary>
/// Share status on facebook
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sharingData"></param>
/// <param name="accessToken"></param>
private void ShareStatus(SocialMediaShareData sharingData, string accessToken)
{
    RestClient client = new RestClient(@"https://graph.facebook.com");

    var url = string.Concat("/me/photos?access_token=", accessToken);
    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);

    request.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
    request.AddParameter("message", sharingData.Content, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

    if (!sharingData.Image.IsNullOrHasZeroElements())
    {
        var imageExtension = sharingData.ImageExtension;
        var name = sharingData.ImageName;
        var mime = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(imageExtension);
        request.AddFile("source", sharingData.Image, name, mime);
    }

    result = client.Execute(request);
}
```

Comment: Does FB even support animated GIF? From what I've seen only the first frame of an animated GIF is shown in the FB feed.

Comment: Yes, http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2015/05/29/gifs-are-finally-working-on-facebook/

Comment: Try to add a giphy link on your timeline it will show you the animated gif.

Comment: OK. You might be correct. However, even on the page you linked to, it says: _Note that images uploaded directly to Facebook don’t work._

Comment: Yes if you upload them as images on FB it will not work. If you add them as a link it will. On the other hand when I try to upload them via their api as a link it shows a static image.

Comment: I don't think this is supported via the API

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading it under Videos. It worked for me.

```
        $linkData = [
            'message' => $gifyTitle,
            'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($fileName)
        ];      

        $linkData["message"] = $gifyTitle;
        $response = $fb->post('/me/videos', $linkData, $pageAccessToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not like gifs with alpha channel enabled. It only shows the first static image if there's alpha channel. I converted a gif to not have alpha enabled, and it shows the gif as a moving image. I haven't confirmed, but it looks indistinguishable from a video. So it makes me wonder if they are really showing a video, not a gif.